# Появление блока по 1 дополнение

Tags: jquery

Есть много одинаковых контейнеров, все они скрыты изначально.

Мне надо сделать так, что бы при клике на кнопку появлялся один из них, при клике еще один раз, появлялся еще один и тд.

Тут мне подсказали как это реализовать, но проблема в том, что добавляет таких контейнеров несколько кнопок, соответственно каждая должна добавлять свой контейнер, а получается так что сперва все свои добавит первая, а потом добавления происходит на второй кнопке, как можно выйти из положения?

```js
var count = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.content').eq(count++).show();
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Добавить контент</button>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
<button>Добавить контент</button>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
<div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как можно выйти из положения?

Можно придумать множество способов, но логичнее будет заключить кнопку и целевые `div`-ы в общий контейнер.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.content')
         .not(":visible")
         .first()
            .show();
});

$(".btn-hide").click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.content').hide();
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button>Добавить контент</button>
  <div class="content">
    <input type="text">
    <button class="btn-hide">hide</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <button>Добавить контент</button>
  <div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="content"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо хорошее решение, а можно еще подсказку, в этих блоках, которые появляются, есть еще кнопка для каждого, которая должна скрывать этот блок, как реализовать скрытие?

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев добавил

Comment: Спасибо ) я немного по другому сделал, но тоже работает как надо.